# Workarounds for gpu-gradient-based sparse updates that circumvent SparseApply* -- are there any in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, gradient-descent

To start off with some context:

- `SparseApply*` operators are not implemented for the GPU (as of 0.11)
- These ops are needed to use Momentum and ADAM and various other gradient-based optimizers
- the CPU versions cause data transfer and latency between the CPU and GPU

I want Momentum/ADAM on a model that uses `tf.gather` extensively in many places, in a manner that does not cripple the GPU utilization. The dense versions of my variables are not particularly large, especially compared to the memory used by activations and other tensors in the compute graph.

Short of implementing these `SparseApply*` ops for GPU, I thought of a workaround, and I would like some comments on whether it is likely to work, alternative suggestions, or just general criticism:

1. Keep track of all model parameter variables in my model in a dict `D`
2. Collect gradients for the parameters in `D` using `tf.gradients`
3. Manually program the adam/momentum updates using dense GPU operations (along with their latent variables) in subgraph H.  (Subgraph of the whole tensorflow/session default compute graph)
4. Compute/apply H

Some background information: I selectively chose a substring from first comment by stephenroller of https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2314

> At the moment, it appears that only GradientDescentOptimizer supports
>   running on the GPU when there is a SparseTensor update.
>
> There can be substantial speed improvements by allowing them to be
>   stored on the GPU. For one, there is no need to transfer the vectors
>   of embeddings to/from the GPU, and instead one can just transfer the
>   embedding indexes, and then the gradients also don't need to be
>   transferred backwards. In one test I've run where I implemented a
>   version on the GPU, the difference in one epoch was roughly 1100s vs
>   300s.

edit: renamed my question/title so that key-words show up earlier in the title.

Answer (score 1):

One other option is to implement these optimizers using plain tensorflow ops and use scatter_add to do the final addition, which should work since scatter_add is registered in the GPU.